# haskell repl in emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, read-eval-print-loop, haskell-mode

Hi i am starting with haskell and trying to set up my emacs for its development.

I have `haskell-mod` and `ghc-mod` latest in `emacs 24.3.1`. GHC is `7.6.3`

i have created a haskell file first.hs and when i do `C-c C-l`
It asks :

```
start a new project named haskell ? y or n
```

my directory name is haskell. I press y

```
Set the cabal directory
```

I have tried with both ~/.cabal and my current directory named `haskell`

```
Set the current directory
```

Just pressed enter as it has haskell directory

It shows error messages :

```
haskell-process-start: cl-ecase failed: cabal-rep, (ghci quote cabal-repl quote cabal-ghci quote cabal-dev quote)
```

How can i get the repl ?

I read that i may need to downgrad the ghc version to make it work.
Is that good solution ?

**Solution** :

I had multiple `custom-set-variables` in init.el and it led to the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### UPDATE 2017

now that we have [**Intero**](https://haskell-lang.org/intero) I would suggest you try Intero/Stack - it works rather well.

With it my config is slimmed even more down:

```
;; ----------------------------------------------------------------------
;; HASKELL
(require 'haskell-mode)
(require 'intero)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'intero-mode)
(require 'flycheck)
(setq flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(save new-line))
(flycheck-add-next-checker 'intero '(warning . haskell-hlint))
```

Concerning the **REPL** you basically just load the file and then `C-c C-l` into the repl (you can always switch between the two windows with `C-c C-z` and you can clear out the repl-buffer with `C-c C-k` (when inside).

The only drawback is that Intero is usually installed locally in your project, so the first startup into a new project will take a while for Intero to download/compile/boot-up - but it's no big deal and you gain much.

---

### UPDATE

Now that `stack` is out and running great I would recommend setting the `haskell-process-type` to `auto` and maybe installing `ghc-mod` using stack.

here is the current setup I am using:

```
(require 'haskell-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-doc-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'linum-mode)
(add-to-list 'exec-path "~/.local/bin")
(eval-after-load 'haskell-mode '(progn
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'haskell-process-load-file)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n C-t") 'haskell-process-do-type)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n C-i") 'haskell-process-do-info)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map "\C-ch" 'haskell-hoogle)))
(eval-after-load 'haskell-cabal '(progn
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-k") 'haskell-interactive-ode-clear)
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'haskell-process-cabal-build)
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c c") 'haskell-process-cabal)))

(require 'company-ghci)
(push 'company-ghci company-backends)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(add-hook 'haskell-interactive-mode-hook 'company-mode)
```

As you can see I basically got rid of all `ghc-mod` related stuff (*stack* works as is with the current `haskell-mode`) and replaced the `company` backend (although this one is really slow and I hope to find something better)

### variables

Theses you usually set within Emacs/Configuration of Haskell-Mode

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; there is of course more in here - these are the Haskell related:
 '(haskell-font-lock-symbols (quote unicode))
 '(haskell-hoogle-command nil)
 '(haskell-mode-hook
   (quote
    (linum-mode turn-on-haskell-indentation turn-on-haskell-doc-mode)) t)
 '(haskell-process-auto-import-loaded-modules t)
 '(haskell-process-load-or-reload-prompt t)
 '(haskell-process-log t)
 '(haskell-process-suggest-language-pragmas nil)
 '(haskell-process-suggest-no-warn-orphans t)
 '(haskell-process-type (quote auto))
 '(haskell-process-use-presentation-mode t)
 '(haskell-tags-on-save t)
 '(inferior-haskell-wait-and-jump t)
 '(safe-local-variable-values
   (quote
    ((haskell-process-use-ghci . t)
     (haskell-indent-spaces . 4))))
 (uniquify)))
```

These are the packages I added:

- haskell-mode
- company (not Haskell-related as is but a dependency)
- company-cabal
- company-ghci
- ghci-completion
- shakespeare-mode (for Yesod)
- company-quickhelp (for nice display of `:i`)

---

#### First

if it asks for your **cabal directory** - it wants to know where your `myProject.cabal` file is - if you don't have one just take the folder where your file is (the default - I think the default/find never failed me till now).

#### in case you need some sample-.emacs-setup

Here are parts from my `.emacs` file that works for me:

```
(autoload 'ghc-init "ghc" nil t)
(autoload 'ghc-debug "ghc" nil t)
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () (ghc-init)))
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-indentation)

(eval-after-load 'haskell-mode '(progn
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-l") 'haskell-process-load-or-reload)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-`") 'haskell-interactive-bring)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n C-t") 'haskell-process-do-type)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n C-i") 'haskell-process-do-info)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n C-c") 'haskell-process-cabal-build)
  (define-key haskell-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-n c") 'haskell-process-cabal)))
(eval-after-load 'haskell-cabal '(progn
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-`") 'haskell-interactive-bring)
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-k") 'haskell-interactive-ode-clear)
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'haskell-process-cabal-build)
  (define-key haskell-cabal-mode-map (kbd "C-c c") 'haskell-process-cabal)))

(custom-set-variables
 '(haskell-interactive-mode-hide-multi-line-errors nil)
 '(haskell-process-log t)
 '(haskell-process-type (quote cabal-repl)))
```

Please note the part with `(quote cabal-repl)` - this should work with cabal sandboxes.
Also this will add more logging information to a buffer named *haskell-process-log* where you might find more about your problem.

I use this with `ghc-mod version 5.1.0.2 compiled by GHC 7.8.3` and GHC 7.8.3 obviously.

Of course you have to make sure that your `.cabal` folder and the place where `ghc-mod` is in your path (I think you can configure this somewhere in the emacs settings too - but it's much easier this way).

#### remarks

- you have to install the package `ghc` in emacs not `ghc-mod`.
- I had problems with different version of ghc-mod and the emacs package before - so make sure that you get the latest with cabal-install and then reinstall the emacs-package (was only problems with parsing of the ghc-output on my part though)

#### further information

If this does not help you please feel free to

- add a comment
- have a look at the [happy haskell programming page](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/)
- have a look at the [ghc wiki on emacs](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Emacs)

#### sample run on my machine

I edited a sample file like this:

[image: Helo Emacs]

Then I hit C-c C-l and press y:

[image: Step 2]

And accept the folder (this is where the file is located) and any other questions with Ret - now you should see the `*haskell*` buffer with a friendly message/lambda:

[image: Step 3]

Finally I can check that the file got loaded:

[image]

Comment: Thanks i found that i had multiple `custom-set-variables` and it lead to the break.

Comment: Hi, can you give your new emacs config with Slack.. or is it the only change of `haskell-process-type`

Comment: @AshishNegi done - but it's really not that big of a deal - it works as is with `haskell-mode`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put together a very thorough response

Comment: @SteveB. as you mention it I should probably add another update because now we have Intero (https://haskell-lang.org/intero) and I would use this instead of intero