# The ? marks in emacs/haskell and ghc mode

Tags: haskell, emacs

Following the instructions in this post: [haskell repl in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603649/haskell-repl-in-emacs), I could run haskell and ghc mode in emacs.

The issue is that I have ? marks, and I know it says something is wrong, but I don't know how to check why I get the marks (and how to improve my code from the hints).  How to get the information what is the problem with my code?

[image]

Comment: Looks like flycheck or something similar...is there a tooltip that appears when you hover over those lines?

Comment: @li.davidm: I see nothing with click, roll over or anything.

Comment: @proseek Are you sure? When I hover I get "Top-level binding with no type signature: ...", but this is from flycheck. Do you know if you have flycheck or something running? (What minor mode is providing that `0:2` in the mode line?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed `flycheck-haskell` package, and then started the `flycheck mode`.
Now I see the help comment.

[image]